# Unable to install CA certificate on Android Oreo

Tags: android, certificate

I am trying to install a certificate on Oreo version of Android. I have downloaded the certificate on internal storage and the format is `.cer` and pin is set for lock screen.

I have tried following steps:

> Settings-- Security & Lockscreen-- Credential storage-- Install from
>   storage--

I can see the cert file but it is greyed out and there is no option to select it.

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/11692564/1168342 -- my `.cer` certificate was exported from Windows 10 and I chose the DER format without Base64 encoding and it installs just fine (not greyed out).

Answer (score 30):

Had the same problem here - Certificates in the download directory were all greyed out.

Pretty sure it's a bug - here's the workaround that worked for me.

I was navigating to the file via the *Download* shortcut in the *Open from* sidebar. Instead, don't use the shortcut. From the *Open from* sidebar, select the base phone storage (labelled as your phone name) and navigate to your Downloads directory manually. Now, my certs can be selected.

Comment: This is the solution, is it a security protection to protect the average user ?

Answer (score 4):

On my Android 8.1 (Oreo) device, all `.der` certificates were grayed out, but @brianwood's approach did not work for me.  Instead I needed to convert the `.der` file to `.pem` before Android would allow it to be installed.  The procedure was:

1. Download openssl (e.g., `brew install openssl` for MacOS or `sudo apt-get install openssl` for some Linux distributions)
2. Convert the certificate to `.pem` via the command:

`openssl x509 -inform der -in <filename>.der -out <filename>.pem`

3. Transfer the `.pem` file to your Android device (e.g., via Google drive)

Answer (score 1):

I had to rename the certificate file from `.der` to `.crt`, then I could install it.